# How can I add extra information in the name of snapshot jars in maven?

Tags: maven, snapshot

Currently maven produces snapshots named like `artifact-$VERSION-$DATE.jar`. I have extra information (the build number, monotonically increasing) that I would like to embed in this name, possibly instead of the date. Is there any default or easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use <classifier> in maven-jar-plugin <configuration>:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <classifier>${buildNumber}</classifier>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: It seems like this would require explicitly depending on artifact-$VERSION-$CLASSIFIER, when in fact I would like to be depending on the most recent artifact-$VERSION*.jar

Comment: @U2EF1, try using `<finalName>${artifactId}-${version}-blabla</finalName>`, This will give you `mylib-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-blabla.jar` in target/ folder, but remain default install name `mylib-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in local maven repository (if you do mvn install) or remote repository (if you do mvn deploy).

Answer (score 0):

The [classifier](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html) field is your only option for customizing your Maven repository file name. It is not however really designed to store information like the build number, which ideally should be part of the project "version" field...

I would suggest that you use a Maven repository manager, which would enable the storage of additional artifact metadata. My personal choice would be nexus, which has a [plugin for storing artifact metadata](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/custom-metadata-plugin.html)

Comment: But it's my understanding that personal pom's would then have to depend on artifact-$VERSION-$CLASSIFIER.jar, where I only want them to use the most recent artifact-$VERSION.jar